# (linear algebra) - Can a symmetric equilibrium achive higher social-welfare than some equilibrium with the same support?

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

EDIT: rewritting the question to linear algebra to make it more accessible.

Denote by $\Delta([n])$  the set of all probability distributions over $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, that is:
$$\Delta([n])=\{x\in[0,1]^n\mid \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1\}$$

Let $A\in [0,1]^{n\times n}$ be a matrix, and let $x,y,z\in \Delta([n])$.

> **Does the following conditions**:

1. $\forall r\in\Delta([n]): r^tAy\leq x^tAy$
2. $\forall r\in\Delta([n]): x^tA^tr\leq x^tA^ty$
3. $\forall r\in\Delta([n]): r^tAz \leq \ \ z^tAz,\ \ z^tA^tr\ \  \leq \ \ z^tA^tz$
4. $\forall i\in[n]: x_i+y_i > 0, z_i > 0$

> **Imply that $$x^t(A+A^t)y\geq z^t(A+A^t)z$$?**

---

For example, if

$A=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.3 & 0.6 \\
0.4 & 0.2 \\
\end{array} \right) $

Then $z=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.8 \\
0.2  \\
\end{array} \right)$ , $x=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0  \\
\end{array} \right)$ , $y=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1  \\
\end{array} \right)$

Satisfy the conditions and $$x^tAy+x^tA^ty = 0.6 + 0.4 > 0.36 + 0.36 = z^tAz\ + z^tA^tz$$

---

Notice that if condition (4) isn't true, then the claim doesn't hold, e.g.:

$A=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) $

And $z=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
0  \\
\end{array} \right)$ , $x=y=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0.5 \\
0.5  \\
\end{array} \right)$

Comment: You might try this question at http://economics.stackexchange.com/, which just recently entered public beta.  There seem to be quite a few mathematically literate people there, and they are perhaps more likely to have the relevant expertise.

Comment: Do you know the answer if A is symmetric?

Comment: Also, am I right that the condition on $x$ and $y$ is the same? Just transpose condition (2) and swap $x$ and $y$, you get condition (1).

Comment: @domotorp - condition (1) means that $x$ is in the best-response of $y$, and condition (2) vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the aforementioned economist. 
I figured out a counterexample for the non-singular case:

Let 
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 7 & 0 \\
7 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 3 & 1 \end{array} \right)
$$

$$
z = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{3}, & \frac{1}{3}, & \frac{1}{3} \end{array} \right)
$$

$$
x = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac 15, & 0, & \frac45 \end{array} \right)
$$

$$
y = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0, & \frac 15, & \frac45 \end{array} \right)
$$

The expected payoff is $2\cdot \frac 73$ in the symmetric equilibrium and $\frac 75 + \frac 75$  in the other one. As far as I can tell there is no 2x2 non-singular counterexample.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that $Az=(\frac{4}{3},\frac{4}{3},2)$, so $z$ doesn't seem to be an equilibrium. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will see if I can correct this later.

Comment: @RB Example updated!

Comment: @domotorp - you (and your brother !) have been very helpful in this question. Care to look [at this one](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/are-symmetric-equilibria-monotone) :) ?

Comment: @RB I've sent him the new question.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$A=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right) $.

Then any $x, y, z$ satisfy the conditions, so it is easy to make a counterexample.
We get a more challenging question if we suppose that $A$ is non-singular, in this case there is a unique $z$ that satisfies the conditions.

(Solution by my brother who is an economist.)